# IE 11 weird issue with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

For some reason a field in my JSON response is undefined in IE. When I run it in chrome it looks fine. But in IE when I write to the console is shows undefined.

Here is my code

```
function getList() {
    var argument = new Object();
    argument.identifier = _settings.identifier;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Vendor.aspx/GetList",
        data: JSON.stringify(argument),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            addData(JSON.parse(data.d));
        },
        type: 'POST'
    });
}

function addData(data) {
    if (data === undefined || data === null || data.length == 0) {
        alert('No data to show');
        return;
    }

    //this.clearRows();
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        var d = data[index];

        var row = '<tr>' +
                  '<td>' + d.Item + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + d.AlternativeItem + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + d.Condition + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + d.PCS + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + d.Description + '</td>' +
                  '<td><input type="text" class="input-field-integer" id="' + d.Item + '"/></td>' +
                  '<td><input type="text" class="input-field-integer" value="' + d.Price + '"/></td>' +  //This field is empty in IE but not in Chrome.
                  '<td><input type="text" class="input-field" value="' + d.Condition2 + '"</></td>' +
                  '<td><input type="text" class="input-field" value="' + d.Stock + '"</></td>' +
                  '<td><input type="text" class="input-field" value="' + d.ETAIfNotInStock + '"</></td>' +
                  '</tr>';
        $(this._settings.fileTable + ' tbody').append(row);

        console.log(d.Price); // value is undefined???
    }

}
```

Here is the output of the JSON:
{"Item":"1234","AlternativeItem":"","Condition":"**New Retail**","PCS":"20","Description":"my item detail","Price":"100","Condition2":"new","Stock":"5 stk. ","ETAIfNotInStock":"","Comment":"","RowReference":null}

Comment: Please include the JSON your receiving (edited to be short)

Comment: You can also try to clear your browsers cache.

Comment: is your response really double-json encoded?

Comment: what do you mean by doule-json encoded?

Comment: What does `data` in the success handler look like?

Comment: Success handler is fine. All other fields is parsed correct except the price field... Response code is 200.

Comment: What does `data` in the success handler look like?

Comment: i mean that when you use a json type with jQeury, normally you don't need to again manually call JSON.parse...

Comment: I had to call JSON.Parse again. It is returned as json from the server. Do you think it could be related to this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've cleared my browser cache and then it started to work. I had to do clear it twice and then restart computer.

IE is very special.

Answer (score 0):

IE might be caching the response from the server.

try adding  `[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]` to the response from the server #WebAPI